# Current ChildView Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to implement a SwipeGesture on my viewcontroller.

The issue I am facing currently is that I cannot determine what the currently displayed childview controller is.

The swipeGesture is added to the container view controller.  And then must determine what is the currently displayed VC is in the parent-child relationship, then move to the right or left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about custom container view controller, it's the job of the container controller to keep track of this. So, you might have your own `@property` that keeps track of which one you're on, and adjust it as you `transitionFromController` as a result of a swipe. So you might have a numeric property that you increment as you go to the right and that you decrement as you go to the left.

In general (if you're just trying to keep track of which "from" controller you're passing to `transitionFromViewController`), there are two approaches. One approach is implied by listing 14-3 in [Adding a child controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW13) of the *View Controller Programming Guide.*

In this scenario, in `viewDidLoad` you perform `addChildViewController` for the first view controller with. You do not, in this scenario, load the other child view controllers via `addChildViewController` at this point, though, but rather you let your method that does the transitioning take care of that (as in Listing 14-3).

If you do it this way, you can just grab `[self.childViewControllers lastObject]`, and that will be your "current" child controller. So, that might look like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentIndex;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *initialController = ... // set your initial controller

    [self addChildViewController:initialController];
    initialController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:initialController.view];
    [initialController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture;

    gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.containerView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.containerView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

}

- (void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft && self.currentIndex < (kMaxIndex - 1))
    {
        self.currentIndex++;

        UIViewController *newController = ... // set your new controller
        UIViewController *oldController = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];

        [self cycleFromViewController:oldController
                     toViewController:newController
                            direction:gesture.direction];

    }
    else if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight && self.currentIndex > 0)
    {
        self.currentIndex--;

        UIViewController *newController = ... // set your new controller
        UIViewController *oldController = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];

        [self cycleFromViewController:oldController
                     toViewController:newController
                            direction:gesture.direction];
    }
}

- (void) cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*) oldController
                toViewController:(UIViewController*) newController
                       direction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection)direction
{
    [oldController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:newController];

    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame;

    UIViewAnimationOptions options;

    if (direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
        options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft;
    else if (direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
        options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight;

    [self transitionFromViewController:oldController
                      toViewController:newController
                              duration:0.33
                               options:options
                            animations:^{
                                [oldController removeFromParentViewController];
                            }
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            }];
}
```

The other model that I've seen some people do is to load all of the potential child controllers via `addChildViewController` in `viewDidLoad`. I don't personally like this approach, but I know people do it this way and it works fine.

But if you do it this way, you can no longer rely upon `childViewControllers` to know which controller is the current one. In that case, you have to define your own class property for the `currentChildController`. So it might look something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *currentChildController;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentIndex;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildOne"]];
    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildTwo"]];
    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildThree"]];

    self.currentChildController = self.childViewControllers[0];

    self.currentChildController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.currentChildController.view];

    for (UIViewController *controller in self.childViewControllers)
        [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture;

    gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.containerView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.containerView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void) cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*) oldController
                toViewController:(UIViewController*) newController
                       direction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) direction
{
    self.currentChildController = newController;

    newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame;

    UIViewAnimationOptions options;

    if (direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
        options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft;
    else if (direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
        options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight;

    [self transitionFromViewController:oldController
                      toViewController:newController
                              duration:0.33
                               options:options
                            animations:^{
                            }
                            completion:nil];
}

- (void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft && self.currentIndex < (kMaxIndex - 1))
    {
        self.currentIndex++;

        UIViewController *oldController = self.currentChildController;
        UIViewController *newController = self.childViewControllers[self.currentIndex];

        [self cycleFromViewController:oldController
                     toViewController:newController
                            direction:gesture.direction];

    }
    else if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight && self.currentIndex > 0)
    {
        self.currentIndex--;

        UIViewController *oldController = self.currentChildController;
        UIViewController *newController = self.childViewControllers[self.currentIndex];

        [self cycleFromViewController:oldController
                     toViewController:newController
                            direction:gesture.direction];
    }
}
```

Those are the two logical approaches.

By the way, the first approach doesn't preclude having your own class property to know which controller you're on, and sometimes that's useful (e.g. if the type of animation you employ is contingent upon whether you're going to the "right" or to the "left), but unless that's the case, you can get away with just looking at `[self.childViewControllers lastObject]`.

Comment: Thank you!! it might take me a while to review all this :)

Answer (score 0):

In a project i'm working on, I have many View Controllers each with their own Navigation Controller added to a Parent View Controller. I know the initial entry child, but I do the following to find the currently displayed children of the child:

```
[myKnownViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0].navigationController.topViewController
```